# Can this function be done with Array.prototype method

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to adopt the new Array.prototype functions, and wondering how is this code can be done with it.

The goal is, return the average value of every 12 object as an array from the original object array.

```
var WeatherData = [{tm:0,t:22,h:15,p:537}..
var AverageWeather = []; 
var temp = 0;

for (i = 0; i < WeatherData.length; i++) {

    temp += WeatherData[i].t;
    if ((i+1) % 12 == 0) {
    AverageWeather.push( Math.round((temp / 12) * 100) / 100 );
    Temp = 0;
    }
}

console.log(AverageWeather);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xd2v62rL/

Comment: Array.map and Array.reduce

Comment: `filter` is a better method  to use for the task. It's not new, though. A `for` loop with `i += 12` would be faster ,,,

Comment: Just a note, by convention only classes or factory functions should have the first letter capitalized, all other variables should start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This becomes easier to solve using the the Array.prototype methods `map` `reduce` etc when you split the data into groups of 12 before you attempt to calculate the averages:

```
var weatherData = [{tm:0,t:22,h:15,p:537},{tm:5,t:13,h:42,p:895},{tm:10,t:21,h:36,p:582},{tm:15,t:22,h:51,p:986},{tm:20,t:21,h:36,p:902},{tm:25,t:22,h:58,p:439},{tm:30,t:16,h:57,p:1042},{tm:35,t:20,h:14,p:480},{tm:40,t:20,h:34,p:958},{tm:45,t:17,h:7,p:403},{tm:50,t:13,h:69,p:460},{tm:55,t:20,h:36,p:967},{tm:60,t:19,h:57,p:419},{tm:65,t:18,h:43,p:746},{tm:70,t:17,h:49,p:344},{tm:75,t:16,h:90,p:651},{tm:80,t:19,h:96,p:646},{tm:85,t:19,h:3,p:301},{tm:90,t:14,h:96,p:770},{tm:95,t:17,h:54,p:1036},{tm:100,t:15,h:79,p:890},{tm:105,t:22,h:32,p:1041},{tm:110,t:22,h:67,p:415},{tm:115,t:20,h:82,p:616}];

var groups = [];

while(weatherData.length) {
    groups.push(weatherData.splice(0, 12));
}

var averageWeather = groups.map(function(g) {
    return Math.round((g.reduce(function(acc, val) { 
       return acc + val.t
    }, 0) / 12) * 100) / 100;
});

console.log(averageWeather);
```

Comment: That is actually a great idea, I haven't thought of splitting the arrays before the `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.getAverageWeather = function() {
    var AverageWeather = []; 
    var temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {

        temp += this[i].t;
        if ((i+1) % 12 == 0) {
      AverageWeather.push( Math.round((temp / 12) * 100) / 100 );
        Temp = 0;
        }
    }

    return AverageWeather;
}

var WeatherData = [{tm:0,t:22,h:15,p:537},{tm:5,t:13,h:42,p:895},{tm:10,t:21,h:36,p:582},{tm:15,t:22,h:51,p:986},{tm:20,t:21,h:36,p:902},{tm:25,t:22,h:58,p:439},{tm:30,t:16,h:57,p:1042},{tm:35,t:20,h:14,p:480},{tm:40,t:20,h:34,p:958},{tm:45,t:17,h:7,p:403},{tm:50,t:13,h:69,p:460},{tm:55,t:20,h:36,p:967},{tm:60,t:19,h:57,p:419},{tm:65,t:18,h:43,p:746},{tm:70,t:17,h:49,p:344},{tm:75,t:16,h:90,p:651},{tm:80,t:19,h:96,p:646},{tm:85,t:19,h:3,p:301},{tm:90,t:14,h:96,p:770},{tm:95,t:17,h:54,p:1036},{tm:100,t:15,h:79,p:890},{tm:105,t:22,h:32,p:1041},{tm:110,t:22,h:67,p:415},{tm:115,t:20,h:82,p:616}];

console.log(WeatherData.getAverageWeather());
```

This way you can attach the function to Array prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can combination of reduce and map for this

```
 let averages = WeatherData
 .reduce(groupInto12, [])
 .map(getAverage);

function groupInto12(rows, key, index){
    if(index % 12 === 0)
       rows.push([key])
    else
       rows[rows.length-1].push(key)
       return rows;
}
function getAverage (tempfor12days) {
  let totalTemp = tempfor12days.reduce((acc,val)=>acc+val.t,0);
  return Math.round((totalTemp / 12) * 100) / 100;
 }
```